# Using the same macro in a different spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

For testing macro purposes, I am trying to do the following command on the spreadsheet ( Copy/highlight existing data in a given spreadsheet and then try to sort). However, when i tried to apply the same macro in another new workbook. I know in the following command- it is only locked to Worksheets("sheet1")- how should i change this so that i can apply in other excels(new workbooks) that have a different name as well?

```
Cells. Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A3") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:B3")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

many thanks!

Comment: Umm you just change `Sheet1` to whatever the sheet name is you want it to work on. You could also replace `Worksheets("Sheet1")` with `ActiveSheet`

Answer (score 0):

### Sort 'Pattern' for Different Worksheets

- The first procedure is an example of how to use the second one (the solution).
- Replace `Sheet1` with the name of your worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub sortWorksheetTEST()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    ' Pick one:
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' the workbook containing this code
    'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' an active workbook, the one you're looking at
    'Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsx") ' an open workbook
    'Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Test.xlsx") ' a workbook to be opened
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    sortWorksheet ws
    
    ' or e.g. without any of the previous
    'sortWorksheet ActiveSheet
    
End Sub

Sub sortWorksheet(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("A2:A3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange ws.Range("A2:B3")
        .Header = xlGuess ' you don't want VBA to decide: xlYes or xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```